# Next.js not-found.js file showing a blank page instead of a 404 message

Tags: javascript, next.js, custom-error-pages

I am using Next.js v13.4.19 for a practice application, using the app router mode. The `not-found.js` page present in the `app` folder is not rendering a 404 page when a non-existing route is accessed, as it should. In addition, any internal route with an invalid slug is accessed, and it shows the same behaviour. Please help.

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation"


async function getTicket(id) {   const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/tickets/${id}`, {
    next: {
      revalidate: 60
    }   })

  if (!res.ok) {
    notFound()   }

  return res.json() }


export default async function TicketDetails({ params }) { const ticket = await getTicket(params.id)

  return (
    <main>
      <nav>
        <h2>Ticket Details</h2>
      </nav>
      <div className="card">
        <h3>{ticket.title}</h3>
        <small>Created by {ticket.user_email}</small>
        <p>{ticket.body}</p>
        <div className={`pill ${ticket.priority}`}>
          {ticket.priority} priority
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>   ) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my mistake. The system requirements on the installation page clearly state that the requisite Node.js version must be `v16.14` or higher. I was using `v16.13.2`. I've upgraded it to the latest version `v18.16.1` and it works really well. However, I am surprised that there was not any error message either in the server or the client about this incompatibility. I really hope this post helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation"

async function getTicket(id) {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/tickets/${id}`, {
    next: {
      revalidate: 60
    }
  })

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Ticket not found");
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function TicketDetails({ params }) {
  try {
    const ticket = await getTicket(params.id);

    return (
      <main>
        <nav>
          <h2>Ticket Details</h2>
        </nav>
        <div className="card">
          <h3>{ticket.title}</h3>
          <small>Created by {ticket.user_email}</small>
          <p>{ticket.body}</p>
          <div className={`pill ${ticket.priority}`}>
            {ticket.priority} priority
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  } catch (error) {
    notFound();
    return null;
  }
}
```

now if the ticket is not found an error is getting thrown. The error is caught within the try block, and the notFound() function is called to indicate that a 404 page should be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked, but it did not solve the original problem of `not-found.js` not displaying the 404 message.